# Tensorflow stop and resume training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow to train my model. I am routinely saving my model every 10 epochs. I have a limited number of samples to train, so I am augmenting my dataset to make a larger training dataset.

If I need to use my saved model to resume training after a power outage would it be best to resume training using the same dataset or to make a new dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question very much depends on how you're augmenting your dataset. If your augmentation skews the statistical distribution of the underlying dataset then you should resume training with the pre-power outage dataset. Otherwise, you're assuming that your augmentation has not changed the distribution of the dataset.

It is a fairly safe assumption to make (assuming your augmentations do not change the data in an extremely significant way) that you are safe to resume training on a new dataset or the old dataset without significant change in accuracy.

Comment: My dataset is made of 3d images and my augmentations consist of random rotations between set ranges, pad shifting between set ranges, and mirroring.

Comment: In which case you may find that re-augmenting your dataset may even lead to better performance overall.